# Using RegEx to match partially string content?

Tags: regex, powershell

I need some assistance in creating the RegEx to match these builtin groups:

```
Domain Admins
Enterprise Admins
Exchange All Hosted Organizations
Exchange Domain Servers
Exchange Enterprise Servers
Exchange Install Domain Servers
Exchange Organization Administrators
Exchange Public Folder Administrators
Exchange Recipient Administrators
Exchange Servers
Exchange Trusted Subsystem
Exchange View-Only Administrators
Exchange Windows Permissions
Recipient Management
Organization Management
```

I have tried the below matching pattern, but it is giving me some error:

```
$groups_to_ignore = ('Enterprise', 'Admins', 'Organization', 'Exchange')
$reExcludeObjects = '^(\s[a-z-]+){1,3}$' -f (($groups_to_ignore | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')
$reExcludeObjects
```

Error code:

```
Error formatting a string: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list..
At line:2 char:1
+ $reExcludeObjects = '^(\s[a-z-]+){1,3}$' -f (($groups_to_ignore | For ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (^(\s[a-z-]+){1,3}$:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatError
```

This is the preview: https://regex101.com/r/WKal3Y/1

Comment: Not sure if it will fix the code, but the regex101 link is not having the case insensitive flag enabled https://regex101.com/r/AlLbFy/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, the pattern still give me error?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use Select-String with this slight modification to your pattern?

```
'Domain Admins
Enterprise Admins
Exchange All Hosted Organizations
Exchange Domain Servers
Exchange Enterprise Servers
Exchange Install Domain Servers
Exchange Organization Administrators
Exchange Public Folder Administrators
Exchange Recipient Administrators
Exchange Servers
Exchange Trusted Subsystem
Exchange View-Only Administrators
Exchange Windows Permissions
Recipient Management
Organization Management
' | Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\BuiltInGroups.txt'

Clear-Host
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\BuiltInGroups.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {$PSItem | Select-String -Pattern '^((?!Enterprise|Organization|Exchange).)*$'}
# Results
<#
Domain Admins
Recipient Management
#>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to build the pattern like this:

```
$reExcludeObjects = '^(?:{0})(\s[a-z-]+){{1,3}}$' -f (($groups_to_ignore | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|')
```

It will result in

```
PS> $reExcludeObjects
^(?:Enterprise|Admins|Organization|Exchange)(\s[a-z-]+){1,3}$
```

So, the point is to use `{0}` placeholder for the `-f` string and double braces for literal braces.

Comment: thank you for the update, it is almost correct.
Domain Admins
Recipient Management
The two names is not matched?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer You need to use `$groups_to_ignore = ('Domain','Recipient','Enterprise','Exchange','Organization')`, you have `Domain` and `Recipient` items missing in the `$groups_to_ignore` while they are present in your regex101 link. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WKal3Y/2).